# Sharepoint Web performance optimization

Tags: performance, sharepoint, ssl, latency, roundtrip

We are running on SSL on following server topology:

1 ISA (SSL Terminate/cache/proxy+AD authentication)

1 Sharepoint

1 IBM DB2 Database as enterprise/corporate DB

1 MS SQL Server as local DB

We have recently optimized the caching, compression, minification, and other ASP.net best practices such as viewstate and cookie sizes, minimizing round trips, parallel connections/domain sharding and a lot more....

Now we are not convinced that the we are in an optimized position as the network resources i.e. bandwidth and especially latency are out of our control!!

The client/browser to server/sharepoint is trans-Atlantic i.e. (ASIA, USA, EUROPE).

As of my understanding the only ways to improve the network (latency) are: - TCP/SSL optimization - hardware/software? - CDNs - cloud or our own ?

Answer (score 1):

Many factors impact the performance, Joel Oleson has written a post on this: http://www.slideshare.net/joeloleson/sharepoint-performance-optimization-in-10-steps-for-the-it-professional

You can try the commercial product "Aptimize", which optimizes your HTML/CSS/JS-code, reduces the load on your servers. aptimize.com/

Answer (score 0):

Thats not easy to answer..

1. Do you have high traffic volumes,
   e.g. how many concurrent users?
2. What
   -is- your latency? Ping times?
3. What bandwith is available to your
   server?
4. What bandwith is available to your
   clients?

Answer (score 0):

Well Hertzel there are many factors that can impact performance, you need to have cache for your database but standalone cache is not the solution for true benefits you have to have some distributed cache.

To the best of my knowledge StorageEdge is the best suitable solution for such issues as it can optimize storage to its best plus on it also has distributed cache which can improve the network (latency).

You can download its free copy from http://www.alachisoft.com/storageedge/index.html